# React component doesn't have access to new state values unless the method updating the state is run twice

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this odd behavior where my `onClick` method `handleClick` must be run twice in order for the `CardView` component to have access to the new state. I imagine maybe this means that while the state is updated, the component is still referencing the old state value of the `groupedCardInfo` property?

Here's the flow, would appreciate some insight into where I'm going wrong:

**GroupedRowContainer:**

```
<p onClick={() => { this.props.handleClick(this.props.properties) }}>{this.props.parentName}</p>
```

this then invokes the following method in `App.js`:

```
  handleClick(properties){
    console.log("toggle click!")
    // this.setState({active : !this.state.active});

    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
      groupedCardInfo: properties
    })
  }
```

Which should update the following state property in `App.js`:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      genInfoList: [],
      groupedObjectsList: [],
      // This obj stores data for cases where there's only one property
      cardInfo: {
        name: data[0].name,
        type: data[0].dataType,
        usage: data[0].app_keys
      },
      data: [],
      active: false,
      // This obj stores data in cases where there are multiple properties to render in the pane
      groupedCardInfo: [{
        name: "placeholder name"
      }]
    };
    this.changeInfoList = this.changeInfoList.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
```

the placeholder is replaced with a `properties` object. This prop is passed to the `CardView` component that needs it like so in `App.js`:

```
<CardView name = {this.state.cardInfo.name} type = {this.state.cardInfo.type} usage = {this.state.cardInfo.usage} groupedCardInfo = {this.state.groupedCardInfo}/>
```

Why is `CardView` only rendering the updated `groupedCardInfo` when the `handleClick` method is run twice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting `active` to `!this.state.active` where you don't have default state set for active. You'll want to set the initial values for your state.

Comment: I do actually give it a default value, I just hadn't included it in the initial post. Edited it to include that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use an arrow function to update state

```
handleClick(properties) {
    console.log("toggle click!")
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        active: !state.active,
        groupedCardInfo: properties
    }))
```

}